# Уникальные элементы в двумерном массиве (паскаль)

Tags: массивы, pascal

Подсчитайте количество уникальных (не повторяющихся) чисел в данном двумерном массиве.

Нет идей как организовать сравнение всех элементов. Помогите, пожалуйста. Написал только вывод матрицы.

```
var i,n,j:integer;
a:array[0..10,0..10] of integer;
  begin
   writeln ('Введите размерность матрицы :');
   readln(n);
////////////////
   writeln ('Ведите массив :');
  for i:=0 to n-1 do
     for j:=0 to n-1 do
        readln(a[i][j]);
//////////////////// 
  writeln ('Введенный массив :');
  for i:=0 to n-1 do
   begin
    for j:=0 to n-1 do write (a[i][j],' ');
     writeln;
   end;
 end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введем функцию подсчета сколько раз число встречается в массиве:

```
type Tmatr=array[0..10,0..10] of integer;

function count (a:Tmatr;n,m,x:integer):integer;
var i,j,s:integer;
begin
 s:=0;
 for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to m do
   if a[i][j]=x then s:=s+1;
  count:=s;
end;
```

Затем используем ее для подсчета уникальных значений. В переменной k будет их количество.

```
k:=0;
for i:=1 to n do
  if count(a,10,10,a[i])=1 then k:=k+1;
```

Что-то более сложное и эффективное не стоит сейчас городить, лучше разобраться с этим решением.

Comment: А это точно не на сортировку задача? :)

Comment: @Alekcvp нет. Более правильно она решается с использованием связанного списка куда помещаются только уникальные элементы. Если вы собираетесь сортировать двумерный массив (как?), то это будет всяко дольше чем предложенный способ.

Comment: Отсортировать каждую строку через QuickSort, потом пройтись по каждой строчке бинарным поиском проверяя элементы из неё в строках ниже. Мне кажется это будет намного быстрее, чем O(n3) перебор всех элементов :) Но да, сложнее в реализации.

Comment: Я же написал, что эффективное решение предполагает использование вспомогательного массива, а я привел наглядное, которое можно изучить и допилить. Собственно вы можете не городить костыли, а сериализовать массив в линейный, отсортировать и просто проверить для каждого совпадает ли он с соседом. (O(nln n) Есть решение за линейное время, но количество символов, которое осталось для комментария слишком мало, чтобы я его записа